# Cannot see memory leak with `ps`

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I am trying to track down a memory leak on my system, but am having trouble doing so. I have a script that will execute `free -h` and `ps aux --sort -rss` every 10 seconds, and log results to a file. The script ran over the weekend and `free` showed the memory usage increased by ~100MB. I compared the first and last entry from `ps` and saw only two processes increased in memory usage by about 2MB each.

Am I missing something, or should I be seeing a process (or processes) with memory usage increase of about 100MB?

Comment: Check slab cache usage as well.